Dragging a D3.js svg path object on top of leaflet map
I am trying to drag D3 objects that are rendered on top of a leaflet map.
I am able to do that when the added objects are "circle" object (tags) but unable to achieve the same thing when using "path" objects.
I am looking for a simple example of a draggable object rendered as a D3 path on top of a leaflet map.
